# subtract value in one table from value in second table - Set result as value in second table

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have two tables. First table is `Shipping` with columns `Product`, `Quantity` and `ID`. Second table is `Inventory` with columns `Product` and `Total`.

I want to take the value of `Shipping.Quantity` and subtract it from the value in `Inventory.Total` WHERE the `Product` values match in each table and `Shipping.ID` is value in url (`$onum`).  Then I want to set the new value as Inventory.Total for that product.

Best I could come up with:

```
UPDATE Inventory.Total 
CROSS JOIN Shipping 
SET Inventory.total=(Inventorytotal-Shipping.Quantity) 
WHERE Inventory.Product=Shipping.Product 
  AND Shipping.ID=$onum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Inventory join Shipping 
ON Inventory.Product=Shipping.Product 
SET Inventory.Total=Inventory.Total-Shipping.Quantity
WHERE Shipping.ID=$ID
```

Comment: Yep, that's it.  Why must I overcomplicate things?

Comment: dont knw why you used cross join there